# Auto-populate Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, tabs

I need a way to auto-populate jquery Tab controls by grabbing bits from the html that is output by drupal. Can anyone offer suggestions? Right now the UI script goes haywire and creates it's own set of div's to match the navigation. At that point the tabs break. I am by no means a javascript or jquery pro so excuse my simple code ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

jQuery UI Tabs (Auto create tabs)

```
    <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $('div.tab-body .title').each( function(i){
                var Str = $(this).text();
                var li = '<li><a href="#link">' + Str + '</a></li>';
                $('ul.tabs').append(li);
                $('ul.tabs li a').each( function(i){
                    $(this).attr("href", ('div' + ++i));
                })

            })
        });    

        $(function(){
            $('#tabs').tabs();

        });

    </script>

    <style>
        body {font: 12px/14px "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;padding:50px;}
        .demoHeaders {width:330px;border:1px #ccc solid;padding:15px;margin-bottom:20px;}
        .tab-body {padding: 15px}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="demoHeaders">
        The purpose of the test is to find a way to auto-populate tab navigation for jQuery UI Tabs. 
        This would be particularly useful for Drupal Views that are grouped according to field data.
        <br /><br />
        <a href="works.html">A link to regular tabs </a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">

                <ul class="tabs">

                    <!-- TABS GO HERE -->

                </ul>


                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-body">
                    <div class="title">Aug</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-08-31 09:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-body">
                    <div class="title">Sept</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-09-31 09:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-body">
                    <div class="title">Oct</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-10-31 09:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-4" class="tab-body">
                    <div class="title">Nov</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-11-31 09:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-5" class="tab-body">
                    <div class="title">Dec</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-12-31 09:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Is there a paticular reason you are doing this in jquery rather than the theme layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy -- Yes, the idea was to have a bit of javascript that could create tabs on the fly, without much reworking of the default Views config. With this little bit of javascript you can basically convert any grouped-view into tabs. The main benefit being that if the user doesn't have js enabled they get the same info in a plain list.

**This Problem is Solved**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs (Auto create tabs)</title>

        <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('div.tab-body .title').each( function(i){
                    var i = 0;
                    var Str = $(this).text();
                    var IDval = $(this).parent().attr("id");

                    if (Str == "<?php echo date('M'); ?>")
                      {
                      var li = '<li class="' + Str + ' ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#' + IDval + '">' + Str + '</a></li>';
                      }
                    else
                      {
                      var li = '<li class="' + Str + '"><a href="#' + IDval + '">' + Str + '</a></li>';
                      }             

                    $('ul.tabs').append(li);
                })
            });    

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#tabs').tabs();

            });

        </script>

        <style>
            body {font: 12px/14px "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;padding:50px;}
            .demoHeaders {width:330px;border:1px #ccc solid;padding:15px;margin-bottom:20px;}
            .tab-body {padding: 15px}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="demoHeaders">
            The purpose of the test is to find a way to auto-populate tab navigation for jQuery UI Tabs. 
            This would be particularly useful for Drupal Views that are grouped according to field data.
            <br /><br />
            <b>Update:</b> The tabs populate properly, and the right tab is selected with a bit of php.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs">

                    <ul class="tabs">

                        <!-- TABS GO HERE -->

                    </ul>

                    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Jul</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-08-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>          

                    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Aug</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-08-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Sept</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-09-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-4" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Oct</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-10-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-5" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Nov</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-11-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-6" class="tab-body">
                        <div class="title">Dec</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Outdoor Adventure Club -- Thu, 2009-12-31 09:00</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For a live version please look here,

http://robotoverlord.mobi/LAB/drupal-calendar-tabs/

Comment: Nice solution. You could possible bundle it up into a module of some sort.